# Plugins to set Bookmarks with Inherit Zoom in Acrobat (Mac)?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe, acrobat

At work, we are required to set "Inherit Zoom" on all bookmarks and links within PDF files (using Adobe Acrobat). I have been surprised at how difficult it is to set this across multiple bookmarks. I.e., the only native way I have found to do this is by manually right-clicking on each link and editing the properties to Inherit Zoom.

This is a problem for a number of reasons. For one, when you set Inherit Zoom on a bookmark, you can no longer direct that bookmark or link to a specific destination within a page (aka an anchor). You must set the bookmark or link to bring you to a page number instead.

I could deal with that and work around it, if there was some way to set Inherit Zoom as the default for a document. Unfortunately, it appears that Acrobat requires you to manually edit every single link and/or bookmark. As you can imagine, this is a huge undertaking when working with large PDFs with many bookmarks and internal links.

I have been reading through forums (Adobe, here, elsewhere) and help pages for hours trying to find an answer and it seems the only successful ones are installing a plug-in that can change these settings throughout a document in one fell swoop. I'm hesitant to install 3rd party plug-ins for both security reasons, and the fact that they are often expensive. We're certainly willing to pay for a plug-in that takes care of this issue, but if there's a better way to do it then I would like to explore other options. There's also the worry that after we buy a 3rd party plug-in, there's no guarantee how long it will be supported by the devs or compatible with newest versions of Acrobat.

This has (apparently) been a common problem and request by Acrobat users for over 5 years. Someone out there has to have a good solution. Any advice or recommendations on a reliable plug-in would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an open-source (Java-based) app that allows you to apply

- Actual size
- Fit page
- Fit visible
- Fit width
- Inherit zoom

to all bookmarks within a PDF document or entire directories of PDFs (enclosing subdirectories included) without selecting each item manually:

https://github.com/beatngu13/pdf-zoom-wizard/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone with the same problem finds this, I was able to work around the issue by creating documents in a LaTex editor first, then converting to a PDF. The anchors created in the Latex editor had the Inherit Zoom functionality, if not the explicit settings in properties.

I also used the software Debenu Aerialist, which would have worked for editing links or bookmarks en masse. It's not a perfect solution or product but it worked.